# Reading Values from XMLNode Class

Tags: c#

I have XML as below in  Stored as XML Node Class, I need to Read Values from XML Tag's

XML Stored in XMLNode Class

```
 System.Xml.XmlNode responseXML = eCartProxy.GetCart(customerContext, "1024396864463");
```

Comment: <SavedCart xmlns="http://dellonline.us.dell.com">
               <CustomerContext>
                  <IsCustomerTAACompliant>false</IsCustomerTAACompliant>
                  <IsSplitOrder>false</IsSplitOrder>
                  <BackendCustomerNumber>0</BackendCustomerNumber>
                  <BackendQuoteChangeDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</BackendQuoteChangeDate>
                  <BackendQuoteCreateDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</BackendQuoteCreateDate>

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemsList = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Items");
var coll = xDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Country" || x.Name.LocalName == "CustomerSet" || x.Name.LocalName=="OrderCode");
```